# How to make concentric circle roads?

Tags: simcity-2013

I can make a circle road. I use the shift key to make it an equal roundness.

My problem is trying to make another road outside or within that circle. It is rarely anywhere near going inside or outside of it. Usually it is trying to make a half overlap circle offset to a side (like the olympic symbol).

I have tried placing my cursor in various places. I can't seem to find the formula.

What is a procedure for making easily making a donut road?

[image]

Comment: Here is a good road tutorial. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cR7wJDAWD9s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, create a circle road using the circle shape.

After that, SimCity will display guidelines in circles above and below the road. Switch to the curved road tool, and then draw the inner circle by following the inner guidelines.

Comment: great, will give it a go ONCE i can get on :(

Comment: @Valamas sometimes the guide line doesn't show straight away, if this ever happens - hover over the piece of road you want the guidelines to base themselves off and after a few seconds they should appear.

Comment: fantastic, Crop circles here i come!

Comment: TIP: Start with an empty field. Draw a wavy line. SimCity will show guidelines that match that wavy line. You can create some crazy street layouts.

Comment: And hold shift before the initial click to constrain your line drawing...

Answer (score 1):

Start with two straight roads that intersect at right angles.

Choose a start point on one road and an endpoint on the other road that is the same distance from the intersection.  Click on the start point, drag toward the intersection, and end on the end point.  That circle will be centered on the intersection.

Repeat at different distances from the intersection.